# Разница между += и .append для списков в кортежах

Tags: python

Пытаюсь понять различия между += и методом .append() для списка в кортеже. Данный вопрос задаётся ради того, чтобы разобраться во "внутренней кухне", а не найти практическое применение. Пример кода:

```
def add_func():
    a = (1, 2, [1, 2])
    a[-1] += [3] # в список значение добавится, но потом падает ошибка
```

И вторая версия:

```
 def append_func(): 
    a = (1, 2, [1, 2])
    a[-1].append(3) # в данном случае всё корректно отработает
```

Посмотрев байт-код, я нашёл разницу в некоторых строчках:

```
print(dis.dis(add_func))
print('--------------')
print(dis.dis(append_func))

  4           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              8 BUILD_LIST               2
             10 BUILD_TUPLE              3
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  5          14 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             16 LOAD_CONST               3 (-1)
             18 DUP_TOP_TWO
             20 BINARY_SUBSCR
             22 LOAD_CONST               4 (3)
             24 BUILD_LIST               1
             26 INPLACE_ADD              # Кажется, это "отголоски" __iadd__
             28 ROT_THREE
             30 STORE_SUBSCR
             32 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             34 RETURN_VALUE
--------------
  8           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              8 BUILD_LIST               2
             10 BUILD_TUPLE              3
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  9          14 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             16 LOAD_CONST               3 (-1)
             18 BINARY_SUBSCR
             20 LOAD_METHOD              0 (append)
             22 LOAD_CONST               4 (3)
             24 CALL_METHOD              1
             26 POP_TOP
             28 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             30 RETURN_VALUE
```

Разница в байт-коде позволила мне подумать о том, что я разобрался в данном вопросе, но после этого я решил почитать SO.
Цитата из [данного вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725782/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-append-and#:%7E:text=In%20general%20case%20append%20will,left%2Dhand%2Dside%20list.):

> += is an assignment. When you use it you're really saying ‘some_list2= some_list2+['something']’. Assignments involve rebinding, so:

При этом про `__iadd__` [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python) пишут:

> From an API perspective, **iadd** is supposed to be used for modifying
> mutable objects in place (returning the object which was mutated)
> whereas **add** should return a new instance of something.

Также цитата из книги *Л.Рамальо "Python – к вершинам мастерства"*:

> Составное присваивание (операторы +=, *= и т. п.) создает новый
> объект, если переменная в левой части связана с неизменяемым объектом,
> а из- меняемый объект может быть модифицирован на месте.

Признаться, я запутался в этом и вижу в этом много противоречий. Если через `+=` объект изменяется "на месте", почему падает ошибка?

P.S. Также не совсем понял строчку про `STORE_FAST` в байткоде из документации:

> Stores STACK.pop() into the local co_varnames[var_num].

Comment: `+=` - это присваивание. В ошибке (которую вы не указали, а стоило бы) прямо сказано, что tuple не поддерживает присваивание элементов. Из того что это присваивание и нужно исходить.

Comment: А, вот даже в документации есть статья по этому вопросу: "Why does a_tuple[i] += [‘item’] raise an exception when the addition works?" https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#faq-augmented-assignment-tuple-error

Comment: @Эникейщик не до конца понял ваш комментарий. По поводу добавления значения в список можно посмотреть в отладчике. Элемент добавится в список и только потом код упадёт

Comment: а, там ``+= []``, я не обратил внимания, решил, что там просто число.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это дефект языка. Конструкция `x += y` в Питоне обрабатывается единообразно следующим образом:

```
# x += y
z = x.__iadd__(y)
x = z
```

Первым шагом мы обращаемся к объекту `x` и просим его что-то сделать с объектом `y`. В результате этого вызова возвращается какой-то объект `z`, который в итоге записывается в `x`.

Сравним реализации `__iadd__` для списка и для кортежа.

```
def __iadd__list(self, y):  # для списка
    self.extend(y)
    return self

def __iadd__tuple(self, y):  # для кортежа
    z = create_new_tuple_from(self, y)
    return z
```

В первом случае список модифицирует сам себя и себя же возвращает. Во втором случае так не получится - кортежи неизменны. Лучшее что мы можем сделать, скопировать содержимое `self` и `y` в новый кортеж и вернуть его. Операция для списка имеет лучшую сложность - амортизированную константу. Операция для кортежа имеет линейную сложность. Разница в скорости оправдывает разные реализации.

При трансляции кода `x += y` компилятор Питона обязан создать такой код, который правильно обработает и список и кортеж. Для кортежа присвоение `x = z` обязательно, иначе результат операции не дойдёт до программиста. Для списка это присвоение безвредно. Почти безвредно.

Что если слева от `+=` стоит конструкция, которую менять нельзя, например `a[-1]`, где `a` кортеж? Тогда при исполнении программы будет вызван метод `__setitem__` кортежа. А он всегда завершается ошибкой - менять кортежи нельзя.

Желание авторов языка сделать использование списков и кортежей полиморфным привело к такой ситуации. Которую, кстати, нельзя исправить не изменив язык.

Можно было бы улучшить поведение компилятора.

Первая идея: разрешить кортежам присваивание, если это самоприсваивание. Ведь в случае списка в операторе `x = z` на самом деле написано `x = x`. В методе `__setitem__` кортежа можно было бы отловить самоприсваивание и вернуть управление без ошибки.

Вторая идея: проверить что конструкция слева от `+=` допускает присваивание до того как вычислять правую часть. Это потребует изменить язык, но, наверно, это изменение можно сделать обратно совместимым.

Третья идея: не вызывать присваивание, если оно не нужно. Например так:

```
# x += y
z = x.__iadd__(y)
if x is not z:
    x = z
```

Я думаю, что никто не будет править этот небольшой дефект. Это даже не дефект, а повод подумать как много мы платим вперед чтобы код работал мало зная про типы значений, которые он обрабатывает.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Рассмотрим байт-код операции `s[a] += b`:

```py
>>> dis.dis('s[a] += b')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (s)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (a)
              4 DUP_TOP_TWO
              6 BINARY_SUBSCR  # (1)
              8 LOAD_NAME                2 (b)
             10 INPLACE_ADD    # (2)
             12 ROT_THREE
             14 STORE_SUBSCR   # (3)
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

1. поместить значение `s[a]` на вершину стека;
2. выполнить присваивание на месте (inplace add, `+=`) `b` к объекту на вершине списка (`s[a]`) - эта операция выполнится успешно, т. к. `s[a]` ссылается на изменяемый объект;
3. выполнить присваивание объекта на вершине стека (изменённый `s[a]`) в `s[a]` - эта операция завершится ошибкой, т. к. `s` - неизменяемый объект (кортеж).

---

В то же время, во втором примере:

```py
>>> dis.dis('s[a].append(b)')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (s)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (a)
              4 BINARY_SUBSCR
              6 LOAD_METHOD              2 (append)
              8 LOAD_NAME                3 (b)
             10 CALL_METHOD              1
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

никого присваивания нет, просто вызывается метод одного из элементов кортежа, и это проходит без ошибок - ведь кортеж хранит только ссылки на объекты, а ссылки при изменении объекта не изменяются. В первом же примере была попытка сохранить новую ссылку вместо старой, и это приводило к ошибке.

Comment: Большое спасибо